# Abrir projetos do VS Code para VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arquitetura-de-software, visual-studio-2017

Eu possuo a arquitetura em camadas que foi criada no Visual Studio Code :

[image: Pastas do projeto]

Ao abrir no Visual Studio 2017 além de ele não abrir todos os arquivos :

[image: Projeto no Visual Studio 2017]

Ao rodar o projeto selecionando o Web.Api sempre dá o seguinte erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual o motivo desse erro ?

Comment: Vc tentou no VS Code, ir em: File > Save Workspace As... salvar, depois ir no VS e abrir o projeto? Eu nunca tentei, só que vi que na última atualização incluíram essa opção de "exportar o caminho das pasta"

Comment: Ele só salva isso :

{
 "folders": [
  {
   "path": "squirrel"
  }
 ],
 "settings": {}
}

rsrs

Comment: o .vs e o .vscode são pastas que o visual studio utiliza para guardar algumas informações da própria IDE, então ele realmente não vai listar elas. E o erro diz que esta faltando algumas dll, você instalou o .net framework na sua máquina?